# Using MYSQL SET @ in Knex.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, knex.js

I have been looking through the docs and online but can not find an example or any information on this.

Can you use SET with Knex.js?  And if so, how?  I want to create a ranked table, here is an example query from a tutorial.  But I can not get SET to work.

```
SET @rank=0;

SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank, fruit, amount
  FROM sales
 ORDER BY amount DESC
```

Barmar's response got me on the right path of ranking using Knex.js.  Here is my final Knex.js statement for those that are looking.  I am able to create the table and list with it.

```
let schoolId = req.params.id;

knex.select(knex.raw('@rank:=@rank+1 AS rank'),'schools.SID',
knex.raw('ROUND(AVG(IF(reviews.active = 1,((Q1+Q2+Q3+Q4+Q5+Q6+Q7+Q8+Q9+Q10)/(10*10)*10), NULL)) ,1) AS average'))
.from('schools')
.joinRaw('CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rank := 0) AS vars')
.rightJoin('reviews', 'reviews.schoolID', 'schools.SID')
.where('schools.schoolCountry', '=', 'China')
.groupBy('schools.SID')
.orderByRaw('schools.SID DESC, schools.schoolCountryCode ASC ')
.then(function (rank) {
    console.log(rank);
    res.locals.ranking = rank;
    next();
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.send('An error occured');
});
```

Comment: Using transactions (http://knexjs.org/#Transactions)  will ensure you are using the same connection for multiple statements. Otherwise each statement uses a random connection from the pool. But I like @Barmar's answer better.

And, the `SET` SQL statement (or any SQL statement) can be executed using the `knex.raw()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work if `knex.js` keeps a database connection open between queries. Variables only persist within a database connection, so if it opens a new connection for each query the variable will be lost between the `SET` and `SELECT`.

But even if you can do it, a better way is to initialize the variable in the query itself:

```
SELECT @rank := @rank + 1 AS rank, fruit, amount
FROM sales
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rank := 0) AS vars
ORDER BY amount DESC
```

Comment: thank you for the response.  I was able to get it to work with knex.  The problem has became more complicated as I mess with it, but I will put my code above for those searching.

Comment: Solutions should be put in an answer, not the question.

Comment: Agreed, but since I was looking for the knex.js format, I wanted to include that in for anyone searching.  I tried to find an example all over, but could not find anything and though your response got me on the right track anyone new to MYSQL or Knex.js might be looking for the same and not know how to adapt your response.  If you want to copy the format of my edit and add to your answer that is fine by me.

Comment: Anyone searching will find your question because it mentions `knex.js` in the question and tags. You should still post the solution in an Answer, not in the Question.

Comment: And you should accept your answer, not mine, since it provides the solution you were looking for.